# Python Syntax Error When Creating Slack App

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial for removing all Slackbot messages from Slack but getting a syntax error

```
export BOT_NAME=$slackbot-destroyer
pipenv run python id.py
```

Error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    export BOT_NAME=slackbot-destroyer pipenv run python id.py
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: That looks like you're trying to run terminal commands from within a Python interpreter.

Comment: @jasonharper any idea how it should it be re-written to compile?

Comment: You don't rewrite it, you enter it at a terminal prompt instead of a Python prompt.

Comment: On a related note, [Python 2.7 will reach EOL in just seven months from tomorrow](https://pythonclock.org/)!

Comment: @jasonharper thats what i thought. I ran CMD as admin and then ran the export command